# Display integer value with thousands comma separated in html

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc

I get value from database using sql in asp.net core mvc but I have to display the integer value of price in Comma separate. Kindly tell me how to do this. It just convert the integer value in like Rupees like something 1,000 , 1,00,000
My View:

```
<p>PKR @item.price</p>
```

My Controller:

```
public IActionResult Rent(inputModel input, int PageNumber = 1)
        {

            var data = rdb.GetDataHouse();
            var datas = rdb.GetDataHouse();

            ViewBag.Data = datas.ToList().Take(7);


            ViewBag.Totalpages = Math.Ceiling(data.Count() / 6.0);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.areaunit))
            {
                data = data.Where(x => x.areaUnit == input.areaunit & x.area == input.area & x.price <= input.price).ToList();
            }
            data = data.Skip((PageNumber - 1) * 6).Take(6).ToList();
            var viewModel = new RentModel
            {
                Data = data,
                //SearchList =   List<string>(),
                Input = new inputModel(),
            };
            return View(viewModel);
           
        }
```

Input Model:

```
public class inputModel
    {
        
        public int? price { get; set; }
    }
```

Model:

```
public class RentModel
        {
            public List<eHouse.Models.RentModel>? Data { get; set; }
            public List<string>? SearchList { get; set;}
            public inputModel? Input { get; set; }     

}
```

My SQl Schema:

```
public List<RentModel>GetDataHouse()
        {
            List<RentModel> dataList = new List<RentModel>();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT *,img.pic1 FROM rent FULL OUTER JOIN img ON rent.id=img.id  WHERE p_type = 'House'", con);
           
            SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            
            DataTable dtdata= new DataTable();
            con.Open();
            sqlda.Fill(dtdata);
           
            con.Close();
            foreach(DataRow dr in dtdata.Rows)
            {
                dataList.Add(new RentModel
                {
                    price = (dr["price"] as int?)?? 0,
                    
                    
                });
            }
```

Comment: Could you please define your current price output and the expected output? What are your getting in `@item.price` now?

Comment: Are you expecting something like , `1,000` But `975.00`, `2,100` like this way?

Comment: yes i expecting like 1,000 ,1,00,000

Comment: Could you please include your `@item.price` defination both the asp.net core model and database schema defination. and Currently how you are getting the value?

Comment: i add the model kindly check

Comment: Check out [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/number-formatting-in-dotnet-framework) for number formatting.

Comment: How do you expect a list containing 1 and 100 to be formatted? How about a list containing only 1100?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Kindly tell me how to do this. It just convert the integer value in
> like Rupees like something 1,000 , 1,00,000 My View:

Its tricky and possible to implement.  You can get lot of document out there. However, all those, hardly be implement in your case, Most easiest but eligant, way I am showing you:

You would simply format like below:

```
<p>PKR @string.Format("{0,15:N0}", item.price)</p>
```

**Note:** Remember that, here [`{0,15:N0}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-7.0#control-spacing) `0` is the index or place holder and `15` is the `number of digit` therfore, `:N0` working as formater.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** `@string.Format("{0,15:N0}", item.price)` will act other `data type` like `decimal`, `float` as well. I have investigate other formating considering your scenario. Thus, its the convenitent way. If you still curious, you can check our [`official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-7.0) as well based on your need.

Comment: it put comma after three numbers like 1,000,000 but i have to do this like 1,00,000

Comment: Alright, then  you should do like `@string.Format("{0,15:N3}", item.price)`. You can set the format you want. This is the way.

Comment: it just put three zero after point.

Comment: Thousand menas `1,000` so likewize. You [`could check here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-2)

Comment: yes it format thousand very good but it cannot fromat 1 lac properly

Comment: So far I know, lac has no format, we have thousand, million, billion concept and therefore, the seperator.